# How to expose kotlin kapt from library module android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, kapt

Here I am using Room android database i have created a abstract class `MyDatabase` in my `library` module and added the library as dependency to the `app` module but currently i have these dependencies in my library module

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"
api "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
api "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
api "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

but i need to add the `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` again in my app module to generate the AppDatabase_impl `AppDatabase` is the class i am using in base app module with base class `MyDatabase` , any way to remove the `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` from my app module? i need to only care these things in my `library` module

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: @MSA you need to add kapt in all module if you want to use room beacuse annotation processing or kapt is  only done if it is added in that module you cannot expose other modules kapt  properties